# Can't create the right clipping mask

Tags: adobe-illustrator, clipping-mask

I'm trying to use a clipping mask to fill a design I've been working on.  So far, when I clip them I get the message that the top object is very complex. When I press yes to go ahead, the outline, and detail of the image are clipped instead of keeping the lines (details) and filling in between the lines.

The design comes from an image trace, with some added detail, ultimately made into a compound path. (if any of that info is needed)

What I want it to look like, with the mask clipping the outline of the flower.
[image: What I want it to look like, with the background only in the flower]
What is currently happening post clipping mask.
[image: After clipping mask]
I'm learning illustrator, and after hours of scouring the internet/trying different options, I figured I'd reach out to some experts!

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to do it:

1. This is a vector flower illustration (Expanded from an image trace) over a raster image of a watercolour texture.
2. *Copy* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> the flower graphic and then do *Paste in Place* <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, and do *Object > Compound Path > Release*, or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd>. Then open the Pathfinder panel and hit the *Unite* button. This will remove all the paths inside leaving a filled outline shape.
3. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+click on the background, and now both background and shape will be selected, and do *Object > Clipping Mask > Make*, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd>. Then *Object > Arrange > Send to back*, or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>. This will move the clipped background under the original graphic. *Select all* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and *Group* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>
4. This is the result

Note: The shortcuts above are for Windows, for Mac use <kbd>Command</kbd> instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, and use <kbd>Option</kbd> instead of <kbd>Alt</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Billy!  I'm able to get through 1 and 2, then everything is blank when I go to create the clipping mask.

Comment: @Maddie Make sure you have both the background and the shape selected before applying the clipping mask. Holding down Shift as you click will allow you to make a multiple selection.

Comment: Wow, it finally worked!  Thank you SO much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The clipping maskis working as expected. This is exactly what clipping masks do. Make the *filled color* of your object the color of your objects in clipped masks.* In other words what is black becomes what was your image, which is what you see.

If you want something else you need to alter your image. So copy the image and delete the areas in the center so you have a compoetely black flower then try again.

* I understand that as a human you like to think that a line is a stroke, but this is not true. A computer is pedantic, it is a fill is its bounded by paths not a stroke jusr because it looks like one. Unfortunately this is not WYSIWYG you have to know what is what in your head.

Comment: Well, even though it's not what I imagined, it's good to know I did do the clipping mask correct!