# clipping mask fills the borders of the shape-photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, clipping-mask

I want to fill a shape(rectangular) with a photo using create clipping mask option. but it only fills the borders of the shape and not inside the shape. something like the problem in this [post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/130133/cant-create-the-right-clipping-mask), only in photoshop. how can I fix this?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you examine the layer you are clipping *to*... It is a "ring" not a filled shape. Therefor the "ring" is what is shown when the clip is applied.

[image]

If you want the "pic-1-min" layer to fill the interior of the shape, you need to apply it as a clipping mask to a *solid* shape (a filled rectangle), not a "hollow" shape.

Notice the difference....

[image]

Clipping masks in Photoshop are only applied to the *visible* pixels on the layer they are being clipped to.

Comment: thank you very much. it helped me a lot.